# OSDev. PS/2 Mouse not working. IRQ 12 doesn't fire when mouse is moved

Tags: c, osdev

I am writing an OS. I have written "some" keyboard drivers and I wanted make a little mouse support, maybe a cursor. I read several guides on ps/2 mouse especially on osdev wiki and copied a bunch of code from Sanik's to start. (https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?t=10247)

However I cannot get the mouse to respond. I initialise the mouse and setup irq12 but the output is not consistent. Here is the code.

```
void mouse_install()
{
  unsigned char _status;  //unsigned char
    
    mouse_write(0xFF);
    mouse_read();

 
  //Enable the interrupts
  mouse_wait(1);
  outb(0x64, 0x20);
  mouse_wait(0);
   _status=inb(0x60);          
   _status = (_status | 2) ;
  mouse_wait(1);
  outb(0x64, 0x60);
  mouse_wait(1);
  outb(0x60, _status);
 mouse_read();
 
 
 
  //Enable the mouse
  mouse_write(0xF4);
  mouse_read();  //Acknowledge

}
```

I call this directly from the kernel after the interrupts are setup. I know for a fact that irq's work because keyboard works. This next code is the mouse handler. I call a printf after I get the mouse_x.

```
void irq12_handler(interrupt_frame_t* frame) //struct regs *a_r (not used but just there)
{
    
  switch(mouse_cycle)
  {
    case 0:
      mouse_byte[0]=inb(0x60);
      mouse_cycle++;
      break;
    case 1:
      mouse_byte[1]=inb(0x60);
      mouse_cycle++;
      break;
    case 2:
      mouse_byte[2]=inb(0x60);
      
      
      mouse_x = mouse_byte[1];
      mouse_y = mouse_byte[2];
      
     
      
      mouse_cycle=0;
      break;
  }
    
  printf(mouse_x);
  
  default_irq_handler(frame); // <- This is just outb(0x20, 0x20); outb(0xA0, 0x20);
  
}
```

The problem is I get 3 outputs at the initalisation and I don't get any more output when I move the mouse. However, the first time I wrote this code it did work. I got a bunch of values outputted when I moved the mouse but the next time I compiled it without changing any code it stopped working which is funny.

What may the problem be? I am running this on QEmu. I can post more code if you request.

Edit: This is th output

[image]

Edit: Printf code

Beware very bad code ahead.

```
void printf(const char* format, ...) 
{
    char * str = format;
    
    char ite;
    int numargs = 0;
    for(int z = 0; z < len(str); z++)
    {
        if(str[z+1] != '%')
            {
                numargs++;
            }
    }
    
    va_list listPointer;

    va_start( listPointer, numargs );
    
    
    for(int z = 0; z < strlen(str); z++)
    {
        ite = str[z];
        
        if(ite == '%')
        {
            switch(str[z+1])
            {
                case 's':
                {
                    char* arg = va_arg( listPointer, char* );
                    
                    for(int b = 0; b < strlen(arg); b++ )
                    {
                        drawchar(arg[b], 0xffffffff, 0x00000000);
                    
                    }
                    
                    break;
                }
                case 'd':
                {
                    int arg = va_arg( listPointer, int );
                    
                    char * conv;
                    itoa(arg, conv, 10);
                    
                    for(int b = 0; b < strlen(conv); b++ )
                    {
                        drawchar(conv[b], 0xffffffff, 0x00000000);
                    
                    }
                    
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            
            
            
            
            
            z++;
        }
        else
        {
            drawchar(ite, 0xffffffff, 0x00000000);
        }
        
        
    }

       //drawstring(current , 0xffffffff, 0x00000000);
    
}
```

Edit: Request to change printf(mouse_x) to printf("%d", mouse_x)

[image]

Important edit:

I just kept making little changes and I didnt change anything related to the mouse code however I got the following output

[image]

This is the output I got as I moved the mouse. It is very interesting because I didn't change anything at all. The code that didn't work before now works and it is likely to get broken in the future.

Edit: I ran the code again and I couldnt get the same output. Help.

Edit: I think I know the problem. If I were to run the program and at the moment it runs click on the qemu screen so I can capture the input the mouse is detected and some garbage is printed on the screen. The problem is that if I wait for a moment before clicking the screen I think the mouse is not detected thus it is not emulated as a ps/2 mouse in the qemu therefore it is not initialised. How can I resolve this issue.

Edit: These are the output with printf("%d", mouse_x) they make more sense

[image]

These are the deltaX from the mouse which means it works. The problem is with the timing that the mouse is connected to the computer. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What is `printf`? Does it really take *integers* as first argument?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yea I think it does I am adding the printf code. It treats them as chars.

Comment: *Assuming* that e.g. `mouse_x` is an integer, then `printf(mouse_x)` will lead to *undefined behavior* as `printf` assumes the first argument is a *string* (really a pointer to the first character of a null-terminated byte string). If you programmed C before, then you should really know how to use `printf` to print integers (the version you have is simplified, and only support the basic `%d` and `%s` formats, but still enough).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I also tried it using printf("%d", mouse_x) which just prints 0. I don't care about the output. The expected behaviour is that it prints "something" as I move the mouse which did actually work at some point. I am adding the screenshot of output of printf("%d", mouse_x). By the way, mouse_x is defined as a signed char NOT an integer.

Comment: Possibly related: [PS/2 Mouse Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877152/ps-2-mouse-not-firing)?

Comment: Also remember that the mouse doesn't send absolute positions, it's rather the *speed* at which the mouse is moved in a specific direction. Therefore it's valid to get zero in one direction, if there's no movement in that axis.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The op of the question forgot to uncomment some of the code that is why his mouse was broken.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I know it sends relative positions but I am not trying to make a cursor yet. I cannot even get the speed, the irq just wont fire everytime I move the mouse.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have added several important edits that may help. I have identified the problem for good in the last edit.

Comment: This type of question is often difficult to answer without a [mcve] and isn't well suited for Stackoverflow. Have you considered putting your project into github or some other repository and then asking over on http://forums.osdev.org ?

Comment: @MichaelPetch I will. Thank you.

Comment: @user3629249 Does it matter...

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli,  Yes, it does matter.